# Detect TLS cipher being used in a incoming HTTPS request on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, https

A C# web application is hosted on IIS, and is served over a HTTPS connection only.

It is possible to detect **if** a secure connection is being used, **but** I can't identify a way to determine **which cipher** was actually negotiated by the users browser.

Can this be accomplished?

*I.e., can the transport layer cipher being used be identified by the application layer?*

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this as I'm now facing the same question?